# Magnific Popup how to use dynamic url for iframe video

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I want to get link for vimeo video in dynamic way like this:

```
jQuery('.overlay.showcases').magnificPopup({
    items: [
    {
        src: jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href'),
        type: 'iframe'
    }
    ]

});
```

but it now works...just show black vimeo screen, this is the html code:

```
<div class="overlay showcases">
    <a class="vimeolink" href="<?php echo get_field_escaped("vimeo_link"); ?>">Vimeo Link</a>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution for this:

```
jQuery( ".overlay.showcase" ).click(function() {
    jQuery.magnificPopup.open({
      items: {              
        src: jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href'),          
        type: 'iframe'
       }
    });
});
```

Hope this will help someone else that have this problem.